# CSS Single line gradient

Tags: css, internet-explorer, gradient

I'm experiencing issues with dreaded IE again.

I have created a single line divider that separates different elements on a page. The code itself is working great in webkit browsers as it would but I can't seem to replicate the effect in IE. I have attempted to use CSS gradient generators but they do not replicate the fading effect.

My code is below

```
#home-single-line { 
margin: 25px 0;
height: 1.4px;
background: white;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(#123f67), to(#123f67), color-stop(50%, #fff));
position: absolute;
top: 55px;
left: 580px;
width: 550px;
}
```

The effect I am trying to achieve can be seen here

[image]

and the background colour is the background colour I am using on my website

Please help, IE will be the death of me!

Thanks for your time.

Comment: [CSS Gradients are not supported on IE8 and IE9](http://caniuse.com/#search=linear).

Comment: I'm aware but there must be some hack/workaround, would it be better to use just an image?

Comment: One workaround is using `svg`.[`svg` isn't supported on IE8](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg).

Comment: try this: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/, it should generate the corresponding `filter` for IE8 and 9 - haven't tested it though so not sure if it works

Comment: @Pete - [`filter` isn't supported on IE at all](http://caniuse.com/#search=filter).

Comment: A side note, your old webkit-gradient code wouldn't work in non-webkit browsers at all. You'll need to add an unprefixed version below with the new syntax, something like this: `linear-gradient(to right, red, #f06d06)`

Comment: If you need IE8 support just go for an image. You will avoid headeachs.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py I'm not sure if it is the same type of filter as in css3 filter but you can use things like `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft` with ie - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use an `<hr>` element and style it. See CSS Tricks code for your example, it looks identical: http://css-tricks.com/examples/hrs/